# 'System.DllNotFoundException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll

Tags: c#, docker

I am trying to run a docker application in Visual studio, but it fails. This is the output:

```
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Console.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Threading.Thread.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Memory.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Buffers.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Memory.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Buffers.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.ObjectModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Haidy.Server.Composer.Services.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.ObjectModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Haidy.Server.Composer.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Haidy.Server.Composer.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Security.Claims.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/Haidy.Server.Composer.Services.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/root/.nuget/packages/swashbuckle.aspnetcore.swaggergen/3.0.0/lib/netstandard1.6/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.2/System.Security.Claims.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.1.2/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll
```

I tried to restart docker, visual studio, reload projects, clean and rebuild the application. Do not really know, how to solve the problem. Could anyone give me an advice?

Comment: could you please specify if you are using the full framework or .net core? Looks like you have the wrong image

Comment: I'm using .net core

Comment: Could you pelase share the Docker file and also the specific version of your .NET Core Application? As I said, looks like you are using the wrong version of the Docker Image.